# MassTransit Queue Maintenance

Tags: message-queue, messaging, servicebus, masstransit

Is there anything built into [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/) that can help manage the queues?

I'm specifically thinking of the error queues.  I saw [the thread](http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/aca10e42485a71ae) similar to this, but I'm not looking to manage it with a utility, but rather in code.

Scenario:

- Web client - commands are published as messages with MT to a remote queue on an application server.
- App server - the commands are consumed and executed. If the command throws during execution, it's placed in the error queue.
- Web client - end users can view all commands in the error queue.  They resolve them one at a time and have them re-published to be executed again.

The first two are easy enough.  The third one is where I'm at now.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: http://twitter.com/drusellers/statuses/5932553953 - "there isn't anything in MT for that specific scenario. but shouldn't be too hard to build"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picked up over at http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/916fd49e1581fc55